# I'm making my own printer, my motors only go in the plus (+) direction, I can't send them in the opposite direction

Tags: repetier

I am making my own printer. I used Repetier as firmware, made all cable connections, and installed the software. The screen came on and I connected it to the computer at the right frequency, but the motors can only move in one direction (plus) and when I select and click the G-code file, it does not react. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: As far as I am aware, Repetier is software to connect to a printer and not firmware. You mention motors but don't give any make/model. It would help if you provide more detailed information in order to help you find a solution.

Comment: @agarza [Repetier also comes as a firmware.](https://www.repetier.com/documentation/repetier-firmware/) (I used this a long time ago)

Comment: @0scar Well, learn something new every day.

Comment: I think this is already answered [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/16333/), most likely, your endstops are reported to be triggered while not being pressed. This hints to a configuration error. Please run G-code `M119` using a [console](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal) to see the state of the endstops while not being pressed. Please add this by [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry for the incomplete information and for getting back to you after a long time. The problem was that I did not set the pull-up, pull-down status of the endstops in the firmware.Thank you for friends who are interested.